# Where could I get the list of Universal tracker HTTP API?

Tags: universal-tracker

I have only found provided `.NET SDK` on [Sitecore docs - Universal tracker SDK](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/sitecore-experience-platform/en/universal-tracker-sdk.html).

However, if consider having standalone `React app` I would like to use Universal Tracker `HTTP API` directly from javascript.

Otherwise, I need to create intermediate `proxy API` that would use provided `.NET SDK`, e.g. the request chain would look like :

> React -> custom proxy with .NET SDK -> UT collection service

Has anybody found the list of supported `HTTP APIs`?

Comment: This blog post by Konabos was very helpful for me. You can find here both examples: working with UT by HTTP API and by SDk. https://www.konabos.com/blog/working-with-the-sitecore-universal-tracker-version-1

Comment: I am a bit afraid of using non official sources. And wonder why Sitecore itself did not mention API if they allow to use directly. Perhaps they could break compatibility any time or so

Comment: Alex - welcome to Sitecore development. 90% of the information you will get will be from "non-official" sources :) The guys at Konobos are pretty knowledgeable ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asked the same question to Sitecore Support and got this reference https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/sitecore-experience-platform/en/collection-service-public-endpoints.html

Seems that this section was added recently.